# Help me understand this theorem demonstration - Dirichlet series

Tags: complex-analysis, dirichlet-series, mellin-transform

On a chapter on Dirichlet series, there is this lemma:

---

Lemma: if $f \in C^\infty$ and $\forall n, k,  |f^{(n)}(t)| =o(t^k)$ when $t \to +\infty $ then

$M(f, s) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty f(t)t^s \frac{dt}{t} $, defined for $Re(s) > 0$ has an holomorphic prolongation on $\mathbb{C}$

---

Demonstration (steps only without gory details):

Let $\phi \in C^\infty$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $\phi = 1$ on $[0, 1]$ and $\phi = 0$ on $[2, +\infty [$

$M((1-\phi)f, s)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, that's the "easy" part.

Also, $M(\phi f, s) = (-1)^n M((\phi f)^{(n)}, s+n)$ by an integration by parts. So, $M(\phi f, s)$ has an holomorphic prolongation on $Re(s) > -n$ and thus on $\mathbb{C}$.

**my question: Why bother with $\phi$ and not say directly that $M(f, s) = (-1)^n M(f^{(n)}, s+n)$? What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1):

There is IMO a more readable proof :

---

If  $\forall k$, as $t \to \infty $ : $f(t) = \mathcal{O}(t^{-k})$ then $F(s) = \int_1^\infty f(t) t^{s-1}dt$ converges absolutely and is analytic for $\Re(s) < k$ and hence it is entire.

Now it doesn't tell us anything of $G(s) = \int_0^1 f(t) t^{s-1}dt$ and this is what we are looking at.

Since $f$ is $C^\infty$ at $0$ we have as $t \to 0$ : $f(t) - \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}t^k = \mathcal{O}(t^{k+1})$ so that $$G_k(s)=\int_0^1 (f(t) - \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}t^k)t^{s-1}dt= G(s)-\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \frac{1}{s+k}$$ converges absolutely and is analytic for $\Re(s) > -k-1$.

Since this is true for every $k$, $G(s)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus -\mathbb{N}$ and $\frac{G(s)}{\Gamma(s)}$ is entire, as well as $\frac{F(s)+G(s)}{\Gamma(s)}$.

Comment: Thanks for this new proof. Regarding my question specifically, am I doing anything wrong if I use $M(f, s) = (−1)^n M(f^{(n)}, s+n)$ directly?

Comment: @Thomas I think I gave you all the clues, try and see.

Comment: Your proof is similar to using $\phi$ since you split the integral into two but I don't see why I can integrate $\phi f$ by parts but not $f$ only. Im willing to think harder but can you confirm or infirm if I have the right to integrate by parts f directly without splitting the integral into two or using $\phi$ ? Thanks